# What are the differences between rm and '-delete' in find?

Tags: shell-script, find, rm, delete

We want to delete the files under `/tmp` that are older than 100 minutes.

What is the difference between:

```
find /tmp -type f -mmin +100 -exec rm {} \;
```

and:

```
find /tmp -type f -mmin +100 -exec -delete
```

**second** - Is it possible to add some **print / echo** in the command so that it will print each file it deletes?

```
/tmp/hadoop-unjar7118762490947462979/META-INF/NOTICE was deleted !!!
```

Comment: What's a "safe deletion"?

Comment: since we are working on production machine , then I want to understand what the approach that is more safe  , second how to add some safe rule that the command will deleted the files only under /tmp

Comment: @yael that does not clarify user Jeff Schaller's question. Please [edit your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/489531/edit) to elaborate what exactly a "safe deletion" would be.

Comment: I edit my question , hope it is clearly now

Comment: If you're not sure what's going to be deleted, perhaps a "print-only" report would be a good start, followed by an "archive" or "*move*" action, then later followed by a *remove* action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two alternatives come to mind for printing the file as it's being removed:

```
find /tmp -type f -mmin +100 -printf '%p was deleted!!\n' -delete
```

or

```
find /tmp -type f -mmin +100 -exec rm -v {} \;
```

The former instructs GNU `find` to print the file name (fully-pathed) before deleting it; the latter tells `find` to execute `rm -v` on each filename, where `-v` instructs (GNU) `rm` to be verbose about what it's doing.

Output of the former would be like:

```
/tmp/.sh_history.6668 was deleted!!
/tmp/krb5cc_6094 was deleted!!
/tmp/.sh_history.18394 was deleted!!
```

While the output of the latter would be:

```
removed ‘/tmp/.sh_history.6668’
removed ‘/tmp/krb5cc_6094’
removed ‘/tmp/.sh_history.18394’
```

Another item to note on `-exec rm {}` vs `-delete` is that `-exec rm` will search your $PATH for `rm` while `-delete` [directly unlinks](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/pred.c#n288) the file. Not usually an issue, but something to be aware of.

Example:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/jeff
$ ls
bar  foo  rm
$ cat rm
#!/bin/sh
echo Hi, I am the fake rm: "$@"
$ PATH=/tmp/jeff:$PATH
$ find . -type f -exec rm {} \;
Hi, I am the fake rm: ./rm
Hi, I am the fake rm: ./bar
Hi, I am the fake rm: ./foo
```

With `-delete`, `find` will also traverse the search path in a depth-first manner by default. This allows it to delete directories that it will not later try to enter.  You would have to use `find` with `-depth` if you use `-exec rm -rf {}` on directories, or you will cause `find` to complain about not finding the directories that it thought were there.

Comment: Maybe worth adding `-xdev` just in case someone does something silly like `mount --bind / /tmp/foobar`

Comment: yes this is very good point , in case some user run - find / -type    , insted of find /tmp -type   , then how to avoid thsi such case , can we add in the cli some additional  syntax that will avoid other partitions as "/"

Comment: obviously running `find / ... -delete` is less "safe" than running `find /tmp ... -delete`; I'm not sure how to address the "safeness" here.